# Identifying memory-mapped files

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I'm identifying parts of process's virtual memory using VirtualQuery. I identify regions taken by mapped files (MEM_MAPPED), but how to determine actual files (filenames) of files allocated there? I suppose it has something to do with MapView* family of APIs but cant figure it out exactly...

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Seems so, thanks, i'll check it tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like GetMappedFileName() is the function you want.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetMappedFileName(
    __in   HANDLE hProcess,
    __in   LPVOID lpv,
    __out  LPTSTR lpFilename,
    __in   DWORD nSize
);
```

[GetMappedFileName on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)